# Best collection to use for small number of key-value pairs in Java

Tags: java, collections, key-value

I'm currently creating a prototype of a Rock-Paper-Scissors program and I need to store the selections in an Integer-String format.

What would be the "best" collection to use, in terms of speed of searching and memory usage?

The premise being that the computer will pick a random number, then the key-value pairs are searched to find the appropriate selection name for use later in the program.

EDIT:
To clarify, there will be at most 5 key-value pairs in the collection, with Integers as the keys.

Comment: If the values are fixed, you could also use an Enum with properties.

Comment: Are speed and memory usage really an issue for a Rock Paper Scissors program?

Comment: Why would you even care about speed and memory usage when you only have 5 values? There is no collection I know of which would result in any noticeable difference in speed or size when used with 5 entries. Ever heard the phrase "premature optimization"?

Comment: You need to add more info on how you are going to implement it.

Comment: The reason for efficiency is more personal preference, I want it use as little memory and run as efficiently as possible. Having read that sentence over, I realise that might be something of an oxymoron when discussing java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `ArrayList` or an `HashMap` would be fine if your keys are `Integer`.

**Both are O(1) and expect unique keys.**

Otherwise, if they are `String`, `HashMap` only would fit.

Comment: both are O(1) true. but array/arrayList may not suit OP's need, he meant small number of keys, say we have just two: `1` and `Integer.max` then with array we need init an array with `int.max` capacity.

Comment: @Kent Very good point. ArrayList would really make sense only they are numbers are consecutive.

Comment: ArrayList is not a Key/Value collection

Comment: @Marco Who said that ArrayList is a Key/Value collection? Indexes would act as keys.

Comment: The OP wants a Key/Value collection

Comment: @Marco Sorry but it's not written anywhere.

Comment: "Best collection for small number of key value pairs" -- Maybe you mean ArrayList<Pair<X, Y>> ? // "most 5 key value pairs in the collection"

Comment: HashMap is not O(1) since hashvalues for different objects are not always different. HashMaps internally use LinkedLists for all cases where more then one value exists for the same hashvalue. Thats why you need to implement the equals()-method

Comment: Yes but it's totally different than saying: "Best key/values collection". With this sole OP's sentence, I could even suggest a Set than can store a key/value pair".

Comment: @treeno For numbers, a good hashcode/equals would ALWAYS be unique, so HashMap is O(1) in this case.

Comment: If one reads "i want a Key/values collection" it's obvious that an ArrayList is not a Key/Value collection! Since it holds only values! Then, if it holds pairs is another questions

Comment: @Marco "I want a Key/values collection" is not explicit in the OP.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno The interpretation would totally be legitimate, when you wrote:  "Maybe you mean `ArrayList<Pair<X, Y>>` ?" // "most 5 key value pairs in the collection" That's why I don't consider the OP as being searching for a key/value collection strictly.

Comment: The phrase was just an example, but whatever. In the questions seems like he wants a collection which handle a pair collection (ok, about a List with Pair<>) but i don't think the question is clear. (if you care, i'm not the downvoter anyway, your answer is valid at all)

Comment: I don't care about the downvote ;) I consider my answer to not be perfect regarding the good point of Kent in comments. But yes, the conclusion is that the question is not clear enough ;)

Comment: @Mik378 - *Both are O(1) and expect unique keys.* - even `ArrayList` ? :P

Comment: @TheLostMind ArrayList is ALWAYS O(1) when the use case is to **retrieve** an item based on its index. Array indexes being unique by essence.

Comment: @Mik378 - I meant this part --> *and expect unique keys* . `ArrayList` can contain duplicates.

Comment: @TheLostMind "keys" != "values" ;) ArrayList can indeed contain duplicated **values**.

Comment: @Mik378 - And what are `keys` related to ArrayList?

Comment: Array indexes are (like) numeric keys.

Answer (score 2):

`HashMap` would be the best one. `get()` has `O(1)` time complexity . O(1) means independent of the number of elements i.e, constant.

Comment: that was the first collection that came to mind, I was just wondering if there were any that would have an even smaller memory footprint than that

Comment: @jbailie1991 - considering the fact that you have only a few elements, I think it is better to think about performance (speed) rather than memory. `TreeMap` for example is O(log(n)).

Comment: As I wrote above, I think that HashMaps are not O(1), since hashvalues for different objects are not always different. If you are unlucky all five entires can have the same hashvalue. In that case you would have O(n)

Comment: @treeno - Well, yes, but the OP will be running taht risk with *any* map.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a `Map` and you do not need a `SortedMap`, [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) is almost always the right choice.

Note that [one of the constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28int%29) of `HashMap` has an argument telling it the initial size of the map. The constructor will use that to allocate a reasonable amount of memory for the map, which is helpful if the size of your map is likely to be smaller than the default size ([which is 16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#HashMap%28%29)).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this is a perfect opportunity to use `enum`s and an `EnumMap` which is optimised for exactly the kind of scenario you are considering - i.e. a discrete set of possible keys.